# Any Java API available for office/pdf documents

Tags: android, java

I'm manipulating following files in my application (android).

1. Microsoft office files ( doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt and pptx)
2. PDF files and
3. XPS documents

I need the page numbers of these types of files. I could find jexcel API for MS-Excel files and iText for PDF.

Could you please suggest Java APIs for aforementioned file formats?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Microsoft Office - http://poi.apache.org/
- PDF - http://pdfbox.apache.org/
- XPS - http://code.google.com/p/java-axp/

Comment: Arghh!  Beat me to the punch.  There's 2 minutes of my life I will never get back 8-)

Comment: PDFBox seems not to work on Android - search for it on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Aspose.Total for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.total-for-java/default.aspx) to work with these files on Android. This package includes Aspose.Words for Java (for doc/docx), Aspose.Cells for Java (for xls/xlsx), Aspose.Slides for Java (for ppt/pptx), and Aspose.Pdf for Java, and Aspose.Pdf.Kit for Java (for PDF files). You may have a look into the features of these components in the related [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/index.html).

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Latif! Well, I'm trying to reduce the memory footprints. However, Aspose package is comparatively heavy and I'm left with no other choice than use it!